# After installing oh-my-zsh, I get fatal message when 'git init'

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh, git-init

I recently installed oh-my-zsh (using theme 'cordial'). The problem is that when I 'git init' I get this message

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'

I switched to bash and ran 'git init' and it did not give me the message, there is no problem.

I figured out that once I made an initial commit it stopped giving me the message but I don't know how I fix this problem before I commit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.